# Change display output with xrandr?

Tags: linux, display, x-server, display-settings

My roommate has a really old 1280x1024 VGA display that the driver sets to 1600x1200 by default and it causes it to display a message saying it can't display the input. I can `ctrl+alt+f1` and use `xrandr -d :0` to find out the output that's being used but every time I do `xrandr --output CRT1 --mode "1280x1024_60.00"` it says that it can't find the display. The mode is displayed when I do `xrandr -d :0` so I already know it's been added. I can configure it to work properly if I connect our TV as a secondary display but the second I disconnect it, it resets to 1600x1200. I need to get it set to 1280x1024 all the time so he can use his PC.

Comment: **Copy-paste** the output of `xrandr` and of `xrandr --output CRT1 --mode "1280x1024_60.00"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after installing other things to fix the drivers the crash message went away and the fix ended up being adding `Modes "1280x1024"` to the SubSection in the Screen section in `xorg.conf`

Comment: Yes, that would have been my next advice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that works, but instead of using

```
xrandr --output CRT1 --mode "1280x1024_60.00"
```

you should try

```
xrandr -d:0 --output CRT1 --mode "1280x1024_60.00"
```

Comment: Yes, from tty1, you normally do not have a "display" to set with xrandr.

Answer (score 0):

You could also run `gtf 1280 1024 60` on the old monitor and add the Modeline to /etc/X11/xorg.conf . (If it exists. If not, you still can try to create it - see e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/217758/how-to-make-an-xorg-conf-file ).

Comment: The solution ended up being adding `Modes "1280x1024"` to xorg.conf although now I get an X11 crash report every time the system boots even though everything seems to work fine unlike before.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have 2 outputs (even the same monitor) and you want to switch within them you can use:

```
xrandr --output OUTPUT_NAME_TO_OFF --off --output OUTPUT_NAME_TO_ON --mode 3440x1440 --rate 120.00
```

In case you miss a bar or other component that would render on main monitor add the **--primary** flag.

You can get the information about your available outputs, modes, resolutions and rates simply executing **xrandr** on console

For further info refer to: [xrand docs](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.html)